# Maven, Jenkins - how to build project to different test environments?

Tags: java, maven-3, junit4

I have a Java project containing junit tests that needs to be run on different test environments (Dev, Staging, etc.) via Jenkins.

How can I setup the building of the project to the different environments and how to pass the  url, username and the password to maven?

Can I use maven 3 profiles to read the environment url, username and password from a property file?

Edit: I've added the profiles to the Project POM:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Integration</id>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>Staging</id>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>PP1</id>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>PP2</id>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>PP3</id>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

How to pass the url, username and the password to these profiles?

Currently the tests are acquiring the test environment details from a property file:

```
 public  class BoGeneralTest extends TestCase {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected BoHomePage boHomePage;
    protected static Properties systemProps;
    String url = systemProps.getProperty("Url");
    String username = systemProps.getProperty("Username");
    String password = systemProps.getProperty("Password");
    int defaultWaitTime = Integer.parseInt(systemProps.getProperty("waitTimeForElements"));

    static {
        systemProps = new Properties();
        try {
            systemProps.load(new FileReader(new File("src/test/resources/environment.properties")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Edit 2:

The change implemented in the test runner class:

```
public class BoGeneralTest extends TestCase {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected BoHomePage boHomePage;
    protected static Properties systemProps;
    String url = systemProps.getProperty("Url");
    String username = systemProps.getProperty("Username");
    String password = systemProps.getProperty("Password");
    int defaultWaitTime = Integer.parseInt(systemProps.getProperty("waitTimeForElements"));
    String regUsername = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5);

    final static String appConfigPath = System.getProperty("appConfig");

    static {
        systemProps = new Properties();
        try {

            systemProps.load(new FileReader(new File(appConfigPath)));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't include any properties in the POM but would use an external property file per environment instead, at least then you wouldn't need to touch the POM when properties change.

In your POM specify a profile which references a property file with your properties in:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>staging</id>
        <properties>
            <app.config>/your/path/to/app.staging.properties</app.config>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profile>
```

Then you can pass this into your Surefire configuration:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <appConfig>${app.config}</appConfig>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

From within you tests you can then load the contents of the property file, e.g.:

```
final String appConfigPath = System.getProperty("appConfig");
// Load properties etc...
```

Actually, you could actually take this one step further... dump the Maven profiles completely and  just specify `-DappConfig=/your/path/to/app.staging.properties` in you Jenkins build configuration.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful. I'm strugglin' now to change the code for loading of the properties file. Any suggestions will be welcomed :bow.

Comment: @AtanasKanchev Take a look at [this tutorial on loading properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) for some pointers. I hope that helps. :-)

Comment: Thanks  Jonathan I've implemented your approach and it's working fine. There is a downside though - now the individual tests can't be run separately because they expect to receive appConfig from maven and I'm getting NullPointerException

Comment: @AtanasKanchev I see, perhaps you could add a system property to your IDE's test runner pointing to a config for your local environment.

Comment: I've found a solution for running of the tests locally via Eclipse.

Precondition for running a single test is having a Run Configuration for each test case that will specify the default execution environment. Please note that this setting has to be done locally per test class.

In the Arguments tab/VM Arguments filed the following parameter has to be specified

-DappConfig=src/test/resources/test.environment.properties

Comment: Several years on, but this solution still works marvelously

Answer (score 0):

You can setup maven profiles, and choose which one is active using -P flag

Comment: Ok, I've added the following profiles to the POM
<profiles>
  <profile>
   <id>Integration</id>
  </profile>
  <profile>
   <id>Staging</id>
  </profile>
  <profile>
   <id>PP1</id>
  </profile>
  <profile>
   <id>PP2</id>
  </profile>
  <profile>
   <id>PP3</id>
  </profile>
 </profiles>

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [Maven build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), since you can specify `<properties>` per profile to specify different build hosts etc. Just do

```
$ mvn -Pstaging
```

(say) to enable the staging profile.

See the Sonatype manual on [Build Profiles](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/profiles.html) for much more info.

Comment: How to pass the profiles to the junit tests - they need environment url, username and a password

Answer (score 0):

Here I use bash scripts to deploy the Jenkins built artifact to Glassfish.

```
sudo /usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin --user admin --passwordfile /root/.asadminpass undeploy PROJECT_NAME
sudo /usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin --user admin --passwordfile /root/.asadminpass deploy $WORKSPACE/PROJECT_NAME/target/PROJECT_NAME.war
```

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT use Maven Build Profiles for this!

It forces you to actually change your build for different environments.

Instead make your tests, and probably your application configurable. The basic idea would be to read the configuration details (e.g. database urls) from some system properties. Which in turn can easily be specified in Jenkins Job configurations

For more complex scenarios you can specify classes to be used for a give purpose from system properties, for example if you want a MockedImplementation for Dev environment and the real thing in QA.

If you happen to use Spring, have a look at Spring Profiles, which support this kind of stuff very well.

If you only need this in tests, you should be able to encapsulate this kind of stuff in JUnit Rules.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. I think the builds themselves may depend on the configuration files. Anyone else agree?