# How to pass paramenters (cucumber tags) from maven/java runtime to cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin, preferably using Maven Profiles

Tags: parallel-processing, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-java, maven-failsafe-plugin

For Java based mobile automation framework development using Cucumber-JVM.
We use cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin for Cucumber-runners & passing cucumber tags.
Snippet:

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generateRunners</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <!--<phase>validate</phase>-->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Mandatory -->
                        <!-- List of package names to scan for glue code. -->
                        <glue>
                            <package>stepDefs</package>
                            <!--<package>com.example.other</package>-->
                        </glue>
                        <!-- These are optional, with the default values -->
                        <!-- Where to output the generated tests -->
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-parallel/html</outputDirectory>
                        <!-- The directory, which must be in the root of the runtime classpath, containing your feature files.  -->
                        <featuresDirectory>src/main/resources/features/</featuresDirectory>
                        <!-- Directory where the cucumber report files shall be written  -->
                        <!--<cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>-->
                        <cucumberOutputDir>target</cucumberOutputDir>
                        <!-- List of cucumber plugins. When none are provided the json formatter is used. For more
                             advanced usage see section about configuring cucumber plugins -->
                        <format>json,html,rerun</format>

                        <!--<plugins>-->
                            <!--<plugin>-->
                                <!--<name>json</name>-->
                            <!--</plugin>-->
                            <!--<plugin>-->
                                <!--<name>com.example.CustomHtmlFormatter</name>-->
                                <!--<extension>html</extension>-->
                            <!--</plugin>-->
                        <!--</plugins>-->
                        <!-- CucumberOptions.strict property -->
                        <strict>true</strict>
                        <!-- CucumberOptions.monochrome property -->
                        <monochrome>true</monochrome>
                        <!-- The tags to run, maps to CucumberOptions.tags property. Default is no tags. -->
                            <tag>
                                <!--${test.tag},-->
                                @ios_e2e,
                                @android,
                                @cover2,
                                @ios_cover1
                            </tag>
                        </tags>
                        <!-- Generate TestNG runners instead of JUnit ones. -->
                        <useTestNG>false</useTestNG>
                        <!-- The naming scheme to use for the generated test classes.  One of 'simple' or 'feature-title' -->
                        <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
                        <!-- The class naming pattern to use.  Only required/used if naming scheme is 'pattern'.-->
                        <!--<namingPattern>**/Parallel*IT.class</namingPattern>-->
                        <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>

                        <!-- One of [SCENARIO, FEATURE]. SCENARIO generates one runner per scenario.  FEATURE generates a runner per feature. -->
                        <!--<parallelScheme>SCENARIO</parallelScheme>-->
                        <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme> <!--Using Feature for accomodating Scenario Outline -->

                        <!-- Specify a custom template for the generated sources (this is a path relative to the project base directory) -->
                        <!--<customVmTemplate>src/test/resources/cucumber-custom-runner.vm</customVmTemplate>-->
                        <!-- Specify a custom package name for generated sources. Default is no package.-->
                        <packageName>com.example</packageName>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now, in the tag section above, we would like to pass parameters dynamically.
Like, run-time parameter /maven parameter / maven profile etc.
i.e. I tried below, but its not working.

```
        <profile>
        <id>TestSuite1</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <app.config>//src//test//java//envConfig//localGridConfig.properties</app.config>
            <test.tag>@android</test.tag>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

[Reference to populating parameter to maven on Stackoverflow another discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498486/maven-jenkins-how-to-build-project-to-different-test-environments)

Kindly suggest how to achieve this
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass any maven plugin property from the commandline using `-Dmaven.plugin.property.name=value` So you could set the [cucumberOptions](https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/timm/cucumber/generate/GenerateRunnersMojo.java#L160) using `-Dcucumber.options=--tags @sometag` to trigger your tags. Depending on your shell you may need to add quotes in the appropriate places.

Comment: For runtime I use mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags @sometag". But for running from Jenkins I need to use mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options=--tags @sometag

Comment: Is it possible to use Cucumber-JVM-parallel plugin for webdriver.io tests? \n We run webdriver.io tests using Cucumber.js runner.

Comment: this approach doesn't work if the 'tags' value is a multitoken expression e.g.,"not @sometag"